# R stepwidth of axis in plots

Tags: r, plot

assume the following frequency table in R:

```
1  2  3  4  5  8
4 22 12 36 24  2
```

The first line contains the possible values on a response scale of a survey, e.g. the answers to the question "how much do you like chocolate?" with 1=very, 2 = some kind, 3= a litte bit, 4 = not very much, 5 = not at all, 8 = i don't know.

The second line contains the freqeuencies for the responses.

I tried to make a line chart of this values. The raw scores 8(the answers of 100 respondents) have been in a variable "test".

So i tried the following code:

```
plot(c(1:5,8), table(myframe$test), type = "o", ylim = c(0,100)).
```

The problem is, that the y-axis is labeled with only two values (1 and 8). I don't know how to get the usual stepwidth (0,20,40,60,80,100).

Do you have any idea?

Here is the plot, I get:

[image: plotting picture]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `"table"` class from the object returned by the `table` function:

```
plot(c(1:5,8), unclass(table(myframe$test)), type = "o", ylim = c(0,100))
```

[image]

It is easier to generate a plot with

```
plot(table(myframe$test), type = "o", ylim = c(0,100))
```

but, by default, there are no axis breaks labels for the unused values.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Both solutions qorks quite well. Do you know, why the line in your second example is thicker than on qour first example. I get those thicker lines on my computer as well.

Comment: @deschen The `plot.table` function is called with `lwd = 2` (see `?plot.table`), whereas the default plot function (`?plot.default`) does not set a certain `lwd`, hence, `lwd = 1`. The `plot.table` function is called automatically if you use `plot` with a `table` object.

Comment: Thanks. So in my case, I should always set the lwd = 1.